# ToString() does not return the expected string

Tags: c#, .net, generics

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication3Generics
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ScheduleSelectedItems sitems = new ScheduleSelectedItems("Yusuf");
            ScheduleSelectedItemsList slist = new ScheduleSelectedItemsList();
            slist.Items.Add(sitems);
            Console.Write(slist.Items[0].ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
    public class ScheduleSelectedItems
    {
        private string Ad;

        public ScheduleSelectedItems(string ad)
        {
            Ad = ad;
        }
    }

    public class ScheduleSelectedItemsList
    {
        public List Items;

        public ScheduleSelectedItemsList()
        {
            Items = new List();
        }
    }
}
```

how can i add "yusuf" on my Console?

Answer (score 15):

```
public class ScheduleSelectedItems
    {
        private string Ad;

        public ScheduleSelectedItems(string ad)
        {
            Ad = ad;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.Ad;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Alot BFree!!! Your Assist really help me. Can i ask some Question? How can i do it witout override method my Sir? İ need your great help or tricks :) Thans again...

Comment: If you don't want to override ToString(), you could always add a GetConsoleString() method and call it instead.

Comment: Also, this is forgetting the missing "Add" method in the other class.

Comment: Actually, in HIS code, his "Items" is public so if that were a List<T> (he has it as just a List, not sure what that is), then you can just access Items directly and call add.

Answer (score 5):

What BFree said, with a slight modification to make it singular instead of plural:

```
public class ScheduleSelectedItem
{
    private string Ad;

    public ScheduleSelectedItem(string ad)
    {
        Ad = ad;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Ad;
    }
}
```

Additionally, you want an "Add" method for your list.  While you're at it, why not just inherit from the list class:

```
public class ScheduleSelectedItemsList : List<ScheduleSelectedItem>
{

}
```

Or you could just create a type alias:

```
using ScheduleSelectedItemsList = List<ScheduleSelectedItem>;
```

Either way, you can use the new code like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var slist = new ScheduleSelectedItemsList() 
        { 
            new ScheduleSelectedItem("Yusuf") 
        };

        //write every item to the console, not just the first
        slist.All(item => Console.Write(item.ToString()) );
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your `ScheduleSelectedItems` class:

```
    public override string ToString() {
        return Ad;
    }
```

That tells the system how such an object should be formatted.

Answer (score 2):

You need to override the toString() method of ScheduleSelectedItems to return 'Ad'.